# jQuery $.data() not returning correct value when data attribute is updated

Tags: jquery

I have a very strange issue. Im not sure why the $.data not returning the correct value after updating the data attibute even though the element has the correct value in firebug.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gv5cR/

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
</div>
<button type="button" id="submit" data-price="100">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#price').change(function(){

        $('#submit').attr('data-price',$(this).val());

    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#result').html($(this).data('price'));
    });

});
<script>
```

Comment: Why not update the data using `.data()` itself?

Comment: I mean `$('#submit').data('price',$(this).val());`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set data using `.data()`

```
$('#submit').data('price',$(this).val());
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/gv5cR/2/

Answer (score 1):

use like

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#result').html($(this).attr('data-price'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used `.attr()` to set the `data-price` value, you need to use `.attr()` instead of `.data()` to get that value:

```
$('#result').html($(this).attr('data-price'));
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gv5cR/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

the `data-*` attribute is only used to initialize the data value if not found in the internal jQuery cache... once the value is copied to jQuery data cache any change made to the attribute will not be reflected in the data value of jQuery.

If you want to update the value in the jQuery data, you will have to use the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data/), instead of changing the `data-*` attribute.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UAqTp/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-price');
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnHemelstrand for the suggestion. Will try to add some explanation :)